# how to display group of images as string in arraylist

Tags: android, android-image

hi i am new to android
    i got the  image url responce from server via json in arraylist i got the arraylist string and i stored it in arraylist

this is my coding:

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

al.add(message.getParameters());

here i add the responce string into array this responce is image string.
the image string is url.

here i want to display the images in emulator

how can i accomplish this please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an idea about this. Set an ImageView in your layout, then load the image in ImageView from the URL stored in ArrayList.

Comment: i accept that but my question is i got the  many url as a arraylistobject use this object how to view the group of images

Comment: If you want to show multiple images, then use a grid view with multiple ImageViews, whats the problem?

Comment: ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); how to get the url from this object